# why is map.get() function null?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, hashmap

My code iterates over a char array (char[] charArray), and finds for the key. The key is then used to find the value in a Map. However, the map.get() function is giving me a null even thought I set it as a value and i am not sure why. Thanks!

```
    parameters for this method are:
    LinkedBinaryTree<String> and HashMap<String, Integer>

    for (int i = 0; i < charArray.length; i++) {
        if (Character.isLetter(charArray[i])) {
            // Why is map.get(charArray[i]) null??
            String char2String = Character.toString(charArray[i]);
            if (map.get(char2String) == null) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("int is null");
            }

            int k = map.get(char2String);
            charArray[i] = Integer.toString(k).charAt(0);
        }
    }
```

This is a testcase i wrote to test the method.

```
@Test
public void testSubstituteMap() {
    LinkedBinaryTree<String> tree2 = Assignment.prefix2tree("- x + 1 + x x");
    HashMap<String, Integer> Map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    Map.put("x", 5);
    tree2 = Assignment.substitute(tree2, Map);
    LinkedBinaryTree<String> expected = Assignment.prefix2tree("- 5 + 1 + 5 5");
    assertEquals(Assignment.tree2prefix(expected), Assignment.tree2prefix(tree2));
}
```

Which results in:

[image: Failure Trace]

Comment: If your map is keyed on strings, then none of its keys are chars. Chars are not strings.

Comment: Please show the code that added that **character** to the map

Comment: You missed out a large part of the code. You didn't even provide us a whole method, and the map variable is not defined anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are putting String keys and trying to get the same with a char key.

Note that in Java `"x"` is not equals to `'x'`

You can either change your Map to char keys or use String array. Since they are single letters, I suggest to keep them with Char's.

Comment: Thank you! It did not hit me that i was putting a char into a String parameter.